# How to avoid instanceof

Tags: java, instanceof

I have interface `AAA`. I have two classes (entities):

`public class BBB implements AAA`

`public class CCC implements AAA`

Both classes have different fields of course that will be used in `Service`

I have Service:

```
public class Service() {
    public DDD returnDdd(AAA aaa){
        ....
        return method1(aaa);
    }
    private DDD method1(AAA aaa){
        if(aaa instanceof BBB){
            return method2(aaa)
        }
        return method3(aaa)
    }
}
```

How to avoid instanceof? In my `Service` I have common logic for both `BBB` and `CCC`. `Method1` and `Method2` use the same private methods in this service.

Comment: Can `method1` and `method2` be a single method *on* the interface, so then all you'd need to call is `aaa.method()`?

Comment: NO, method1 and method2 are private methods in Service with a little bit different steps to execute, eg only in method2 I call aaa.getSomeObject()...

Comment: _Why_ do you want to avoid `instanceof`?

Comment: I don't know, maybe that's the only solution in this case? But instanceof is considered smell code...

Comment: 'Code smell' is a cliche, and like most cliches, doesn't accurately describe all situations.

Comment: OK so it looks like instanceof is the only solution in this case

Comment: Visitor pattern.

Comment: @user207421 Does't look like a use case for the *visitor* pattern, rather a *strategy* pattern. In the visitor patter you want an action to be performed on all the objects in a complex structure, here you just want to choose the implementation based on the object type.

Comment: "Method1 and Method2". – Did yo amen those to be lowercase: method1 and method2?

Comment: Not clear. Your last two sentences puzzle me, as I cannot grasp what point you intend to convey. I assume they mean to explain why you object to using `instanceof`, but I cannot see the why.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would recommend to have a common method in the interface AAA, like:

```
public interface AAA {
    void method1();
}
```

and make both inherited classes to implement this method. In this case you will have to call only one method which will be automatically chosen based on the exact instance.

```
public class Service() {
    public void ddd(AAA aaa){
        aaa.method1();
    }
}

...

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AAA b = new BBB();
        AAA c = new CCC();

        new Service().ddd(b); // b.method1() will be called
        new Service().ddd(c); // c.method1() will be called
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I'd like to leave all the logic in Service

Comment: @Matley Not exactly. You should leave all the logic **which is dependent on which instance of the object it is** on the Service, not all the logic at all. If the *reason* for choosing a method is `if (aaa instanceof BBB)`, then this is exactly the case. And **yes**, `instanceof` is a code smell :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek I don't see this. I updated a little bit my code above. Additionally BBB and CCC are entities

Comment: You have all you need in this Dmitrii's answer.

Comment: But in my Service I have injected other services... I can't move some logic from service to my classes (entities) because in my service methods I use other service's methods

Comment: Maybe I should add to AAA interface some method like isTypeBBB and then aaa.isTypeBBB()

Comment: The thing that by moving that kind of logic to service you are breaking the idea of polymorphism, saying that the right method of the right instance will be invoked without your interference. You can feel free to leave the business code logic in the services, that's why you need them basically, but the polymorphism mechanism is recommended to use exactly in the way I described :) Also would be good for incapsulation, so every implementation knows exactly how to do their part of logic

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this may be unorthodox but it works unless there is some other requirement that is missing from your code.  I am not using interface AAA method for anything but can be added if required.

But I don't really see any problem using `instanceof`.

```
class Service {    
    public DDD returnDDD(AAA aaa) {
        return switch(aaa.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
            case "BBB" -> method2((BBB)aaa); // casting depends on method
                                             // signatures
            case "CCC" -> method3((CCC)aaa);
            default -> null; // or some appropriate return value.
        };
    }
    public DDD method2(BBB b) {
        System.out.println("Calling method2");
        return new DDD();
    }
    public DDD method3(CCC c) {
        System.out.println("Calling method3");
        return new DDD();
    }
}
```

prints

```
calling method2
calling method3
```

Here is how I would slightly modify your existing code.  It casts `AAA` to the appropriate subtype so you can make use of each class' attributes.  The enhanced `instanceof` helps with this.

```
class Service {
    public DDD returnDDD(AAA aaa){
        return method1(aaa);
    }
    private DDD method1(AAA aaa){
        if(aaa instanceof BBB bbb){ // bbb cast for you
            return method2(bbb);
        }
        return method3((CCC)aaa); // do it explicitly
    }
}
```

The above presumes that `method2` and `method3` can accept the subtypes as arguments based on the method signatures.  Otherwise, they may need to be cast internally to the method to access subtype attributes.

Comment: OK, thanks, maybe instanceof is really nothing bad in this case...

Comment: @Matley  I modified my example with casting and also recommended a few changes to your code.  Their efficacy is dependent on the method signatures which are not apparent to me.